# How to correctly implement the merge sort of array in Java using my solution?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, array-merge

**This solution is work fine for me but i got a question. When I debuged my programm i was noticed that for example for this input(when i test a programm correct work) ->   int[] arr = {1,3};
int[] arr1 = {2,4};
I see that my index of the first array is increasing, for some reason, and my debugger shows that
at the same stage, the array is out of range. The program works with this too, but I would like to
know how in theory it is possible to fix this or does it make no sense and everything works
correctly? I also tried various checks for If (), but nothing fixed the problem. I hope I brought you
the essence of the problem.**

```
public static int[] mergeArr(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
         int[] result = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
          int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
           if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
                result[k++] = arr1[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                result[k++] = arr2[j];
                j++;
            }
                System.arraycopy(arr1, i, result, k, arr1.length - i);
                System.arraycopy(arr2, j, result, k, arr2.length - j);
    }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program will ignore the first little element, example, with the two arrays you gave above, 1 will not be in the result array.

Comment: Why are you calling `System.arraycopy()`? Try deleting those 2 lines. Also change your loop to `for (int k = 0; k < result.length; k++)`

Comment: @Bohemian 
this only aggravated my situation and now I really get an error, it seems to me that solving this problem with a for loop is not a good idea.

Comment: @Bohemian  If we're talking about System.arraycopy,  I use it to write the so-called remaining "tail" in memory. Without this method, I will not be able to correctly get the result I want, and since when comparing the last indices, I will not use array copying, I will simply get 0 in the last position of the array.